# Temporarily disable foreign key constraints while creating tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, foreign-keys, ddl

I have DDL Script for schema. I want to run that script but it contains foreign key constraints for another table which is not yet created by DDL.

How can I disable these constraints in ***PostgreSQL***.

Comment: You can't. You need to move those statements to the end of the script.

Comment: but same functionality is available in MySql

Comment: Are you saying you can create a foreign key constraint in MySQL referencing a table that does not exist? Sounds like a really strange feature

Comment: table will be created later...

Comment: we use **SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;**

Comment: As mentioned, just create the objects before you reference them. What if you were to reference something and forget to give it a place to look?

Comment: sure, I will do that :)